# Redirect to Ionic app from link clicked from InAppbrowser opened html pages

Tags: android, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am using cordova `InAppbrowser` plugin to open pages from ionic app. I have used this ccavenue payment page links in `inAppbrowser`. There is `cancellation/redirection` url in ccavenue which will get back to html page which is opening in inAppbrowser. I want to get back to ionic mobile app page when clicked on link in redirected html page. I am using `CustomURLScheme` plugin for this. But it is working  only from normal browser view , not from `InAppBrowser` page view.

Here is the error I am getting :

```
net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

I have used/changed intent filters in Android Manifest files , config.xml files for allow origins etc as well , but no use . Can you please help in this.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with `InAppBrowser` `loadstop` and `loadstart` methods to open , redirect: 
Here is the loadstop code

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function (e, event) {

                    if (event.url == 'actionurl') {
                      $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
                          $timeout(function () {   
                      $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                      $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                      $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableAnimate: true,disableBack: true , historyRoot: true});
                          $state.go('redirect url', {}, { reload: true });
                        }, 30);

                        }

                         else if(event.url == 'actionurl'){
                      $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
                          $timeout(function () {   
                      $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                      $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                      $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableAnimate: true,disableBack: true , historyRoot: true});
                          $state.go('redirect url', {}, { reload: true });
                        }, 30);

                        }

      });
```

It worked well